# Angular password validation with show password

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to have password validation with Angular. However when I click my show password icon, if the password entered is wrong, it wont show the password the first time, the valdiation runs and the field goes red. Next time I click it shows password. How can I get around this? I tried an ng-click setting a variable to true when I click show, and then checking it in an ng-show before showing that red class, but it didnt work

```
<div id="registerFormFields">
    <div class="loginField">
        <input type="text" id="dn-login-modal-register-login" placeholder="Email" onblur="EZEMAIN.loginRegisterModal.loginCheck(this)" />
        <span class="dn-login-modal-login-check fa"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="dn-login-modal-login-error" style="color:red;display:none;" data-ng-show="">@T("Invalid_Email", "Validation")</p>

    <div class="passwordField">
        <input type="password" id="dn-login-modal-register-password" placeholder="Password" onblur="EZEMAIN.loginRegisterModal.passwordCheck(this)" />
        <a href="#" class="dn-show-password  fa fa-eye" tabindex="-1"></a>
        <span class="dn-login-modal-password-check fa"></span>
    </div>

    <p>@T("Register_PasswordPlaceholder", "Fields")</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can to use ng-show and ng-hide to alternate and input password and an input text

Comment: some thing like this would help you.. <input ng-show="showpassword" type="text" ng-model="password">
<input ng-hide="showpassword" type="password" ng-model="password">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showpassword" ng-checked="false">